# How to remove iCloud alias from iMessage

Tags: iphone, icloud, email, messages, alias

I created an alias for my iCloud email address and then added it as another address I could send and receive iMessages from.

I have subsequently deleted the alias from iCloud email. However, the alias still exists as a address I can send/recieve iMessages from.

On my iPhone I can still tap the i button to get info, and remove the alias. This allows me to remove the email address from my iPhone (it claims: You will no longer be able to receive iMessages at XXX@icloud.com on any device.) However if I turn off iMessages and turn it back on the alias reappears. The alias also shows in Messages on Mac, and there doesn't appear to be anyway to remove it from Messages for Mac.

Ideally I want to permanently delete the alias from iMessage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok – think I've sorted it. I had to remove the email address from the Manage your Apple ID: https://appleid.apple.com/signin

The email alias had become an Alternate Email address. Deleting it there removed it from iMessages after signing out and then back in.

Comment: Not seeing this option (remove) once signed into AppleID site

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to permanently delete the alias, but in the iMessages settings, you can find a list of the email addresses you can send/receive from, and you can uncheck ones that you don't want to use.  You could uncheck the email to remove it from receiving/sending iMessages, but I don't know how to delete aliases.

Comment: I read that an e-mail alias cannot be deleted. If someone knows otherwise, please let us know.